# Why would a UV BASIC (compile) command hang?

Tags: universe, u2, rocket-u2

An empty item is created in the .O file, but the BASIC command never returns to the > prompt.

There is 5-month-old object, so the BASIC command **has** worked in the past.

```
Windows Server 2016 Datacenter running on a VM

    RELLEVEL
001 X
002 11.2.5
003 PICK
004 PICK.FORMAT
005 11.2.5
```

Comment: I know this is a long shot, but I would be grateful if you could share what locks are currently active -  LIST.READU command

Comment: No locks or semaphores active.

Comment: If you haven't already, make sure you have an ERRLOG file in your UV directory by creating an empty file with the name "ERRLOG". If it exists already, are there any new entries after you run the compile and it hangs?

Comment: In the past, I've used ProcMon from SysInternals to see what Universe is doing silently through the filesystem or OS. If you agree that this might forward your investigation, please post what you find when running ProcMon and then trying to compile the program. Looks like the download link for ProcMon is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. I created ERRLOG but it didn't pick anything up.  I'll reach out to the server owner about Sysinternals..

Comment: And last suggestion is just to reach out to Rocket support through their ticketing system or call them up. The benefit to talking to someone on the phone is you may be able to get them into a screenshare meeting where you can show the rep exactly what you're seeing. Make sure you have your Universe license details before reaching out to Rocket. 
Support portal/Ticketing system: https://my.rocketsoftware.com/RocketCommunity/RCLanding)

Comment: Is it only that code object that exhibits this behavior? I would try a different one in the same file, and then even create a new file and see if it persists there.  On a Linux box I would suspect permissions first and windows permissions are even murkier.

Comment: I've tried different source code.  The issue is winding its way towards Rocket.  Thanks folks!

Comment: @RossMorrissey If it's not too much to ask, please take some time to answer your own question after you (or Rocket) find out the solution for your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code was missing a final newline.  Notepad++. Sigh.